# Label text is 'nil', inspite of assigning some text

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, label, uitableview

I am working on an app. I have a tableview. I set a separate class for **TableView Cell** called '**cellTable**'. I am using this class in another named '**resultViewController**' by importing .h file of cell. I declared,

```
cellTable *cellElement;
```

in 'resultViewControler.h'. I tried to change the label declared in '**cellTable**' in '**resultViewController**' using

```
cellElement.resultname.text = testNamesA[indexPath.row];
```

I am getting '**nil**' for '**cellElement.resultname.text**' this, inspite '**testNamesA[indexPath.row]**' has some value. The screenshot shows the exact picture about issue,
[image: Clarification]

Please help me in solving this...

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `cellElement`? Why do you even have `cellElement`? Why is `cell` not a local variable? Why aren't you setting the properties of `cell` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: You need to create a new cell (by reusing) with `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I think you have missed initializing the cellElement. So it is coming null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the properties of the cell in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, so is not in

```
 cellElement.resultname.text = testNamesA[indexPath.row];
```

it is

```
 cell.resultname.text = testNamesA[indexPath.row];
```

For example

```
#import "yourTableViewCell.h"
```

Now change the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath to

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewcellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 yourTableViewCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

cell.resultname.text = testNamesA[indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

For an example, you can go [here](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/).

Comment: Why isn't `cellElement` a local variable?

Comment: @rmaddy - some one modify the answer

Comment: It's your answer. Don't allow people to make bad edits. Fix it.

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I understood is you created separate UItableViewCell and you imported that cell in ViewController.But you don't know how to call and use that custom cell in table view delegate methods.

I tell you now.Once you import the custom cell you need to call the below lines of code in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

**If you create cellTable with xib**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
   cellTable *cellElement = (cellTable *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
   NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"cellTable" owner:self options:nil];
   if(cellElement == nil){
        cellElement = nib[0];
   }
   cellElement.resultname.text = testNamesA[indexPath.row];
   return cellElement;
}
```